# How do I drag an object in an iframe using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to drag an object from one location to another location in an iframe.

But I'm getting movetargetoutofboundsexception. How do I find coordinates to which I can move the object?

> Exception in thread "main" `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`: Given coordinates (552, 440) are outside the document. Error: `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError`: The target location (552, 440) is not on the webpage.

```
FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();
prof.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);

driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/draggable/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

// WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/iframe"));
// System.out.println(frame1.getLocation());

driver.switchTo().frame(0);
Actions act = new Actions(driver);

WebElement src = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='draggable']"));
System.out.println(src.getText());

act.dragAndDropBy(src, 474, 360).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more or less okay.

The only thing that is wrong is the amount of move possible to make. If you lowered your offsets to, say, 100 px, it would have worked. I found out the maximums (on my computer's Firefox) are 572 and 338 px.

Now, these numbers are not random. If you print out the size of the `<iframe>` element, you'll get `(584, 350)`. If you print out the initial location of the `draggable` element inside the `<iframe>`, you'll get `(8, 8)`. When you subtract those, you'll get 576 and 342 px which is very close to our empirical result. Actually, it differs exactly by 4 px in both directions. To be honest, I don't know where those 4 px come from. It might be some kind of border.

Only one thing is certain. For obvious reasons, WebDriver makes sure you won't drag an element out of the frame you are currently in.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/draggable/");

WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println(iFrame.getSize());
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);

WebElement draggable = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
System.out.println(draggable.getLocation());
new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(draggable, 572, 338).perform();
```

Comment: tried with this code and still got the same error               "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Given coordinates (476, 440) are outside the document."

Comment: @user2744479 I used `572, 338` which has lower `y` coordinate than your `440`. I also explained how I got that number. Either try the same maximal coordinates (or any lower), or discover your own maximum coordinates by the approach given above.